Page Load Runs Twice When HREF Attribute Set to "#" in Link Tag
I'm experiencing something weird, that I need help understanding. When I use a link tag with the "href" attribute set to "#", it causes the Page Load event to run twice.
For example, in the following link tag, I'm using "#" as the value for the "href" attribute. I'm using this in place of using a real "shorcut icon" and only to avoid the javascript warning/error. So, I could simply remove it, but I'd like to understand what is goin on (or how to fix it, without removing it):
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

Sample HTML:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Example</title>
    <!-- The "href=#" in the following link tag triggers the 'Page load' event to run twice. -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>My Example</h1>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Sample VB.NET Code Behind Page:
Partial Class myexample
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'This is triggered twice.
    End Sub
End Class

This also happens with using it for "stylesheet" link tags as shown below:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#" />  


Well, if you placing a link, and it not legal, then best guess is asp.net tries to load the link, fails, and that error triggers the page load 2 times. Given that web forms been around for 20+ years, and given this is the first time I seen anyone note this error? Nothing to see here, move along!.  In other words, don't place illegal markup in your pages, and you won't have weird things occur.  If you place a valid link, then it should work just fine.  It also does not trigger page load 2x if you leave out the href attribute.  So, invalid markup ALWAYS is a VERY bad idea here.

href="#" practically is a relative URL, and will resolve to the same URL as your current document (minus any fragment that might have had.) And your browser has no idea that you tried to be "clever" and only put this there to avoid some other error - it assumes this is the URL you want it to request, for the shortcut icon. And so it does.

I found a solution on Stack Overflow at the link below. It solves the javascript error, which was my original intent, while preventing the double page load. The answer is provided a few posts down.
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=" data-note="Optional. This was only ddded to prevent the 'favicon.ico' error in the console.">

Link:
Link to Forum Post

ASP might just be doing this because # means "the current page" (like when you set # to be the value of an <a> tag and click it), so when you try to do this elsewhere, it is reading it wrong and attempting to load the current page as the resource for the favicon, therefore loading the page twice.
